# Getting a function to execute when a page loads

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var X = $(window).height();
    $('#windowheight').text(X);
});
```

I'd like for it to also run when the page loads.
I thought I could do that using () at the end of the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

By the way you can't use () at the end of the definition as you expected because `resize` (in your sample) is a method call (not a definition).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

In this, we're passing a function to the jQuery object, which understands by this that we want it to run when the page is loaded and ready.  The slightly more verbose and archaic way to do this is to pass the function to `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: This does not trigger the resize event handler function when the page loads, which is what I think the OP wanted.

Comment: It attaches a function to the resize event, but it doesn't trigger the event. In this fiddle I've put an alert in the event handler, it doesn't appear on page load: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/pvdKS/

Comment: it just binds resize event to window object when document loads, but does not trigger it.

Comment: Now that the answer has been edited, the above comments don't make much sense, but I'm going to leave them there as they include a link to a fiddle in which the code suggested by the original answer is still accessible.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var X = $(window).height();
        $('#windowheight').text(X);
    });

});
```

or

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var X = $(window).height();
        $('#windowheight').text(X);
    });
});
```

both works